# Why is AWS's Chalice for Python not respecting my virtualenv?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice

I'm attempting to deploy a chalice application following the tutorial. I'm using a virtualenv with python3.6. My application is dependent on a github repo in the requirements.txt and that repo's requirements.txt depends on several libraries.

I can run the application just fine with `python -i app.py` and I can execute my endpoints properly live in the REPL.

However, when I run `chalice deploy` I get an error complaining about a module required by the github repo I require.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chalice/deploy/packager.py", line 715, in download_all_dependencies
raise NoSuchPackageError(str(package_name))
NoSuchPackageError: Could not satisfy the requirement: PyQt5>=5.8.1
```

Notice, however, that this chalice library being used is 2.7. I'm in a virtualenv that is set to python3.6.

I realized that I had previously installed chalice globally, which might have been a mistake. So I pip uninstalled chalice globally, but it's still installed in my virtualenv.

Now rerunning chalice, I get

```
$ chalice --version
bash: /usr/local/bin/chalice: No such file or directory
```

I tried rerunning the install of chalice to the local virtualenv but it didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're sure the venv is activated before you run the script, right?

Comment: Where are you running the command from? The Chalice should be installed inside the project folder and the use a venv

Answer (score 1):

It could be multiple reasons.

I'm assuming your virtualenv is called venv, if not change it accordingly.

**You have not activated your virtualenv.**

Fix:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

**You activated your virtualenv, but the path does not match.**

Fix:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/[yourpath]/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

If `/Users/[yourpath]/venv/bin` is not correct, check:

```
grep "VIRTUAL_ENV=" venv/bin/activate
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/[yourpath]/venv"
```

Then update `venv/bin/activate` accordingly.

Note: The virtualenv folder should not be added into your repo. This may be the source of your issues.

If you want to ensure everyone has matching dependencies run:

```
python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```